# Jquery slider and draggable dont work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, draggable

I'm making a banner were you can resize and drag the image. I works fine in jsfiddle. But for some reason it dont work on my webpage.

Here is the example in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DennisBetman/tnaGA/

And here is how it looks on my webpage:
http://jewelbeast.com/posts/imgreplace.html

So if you can see. The slider dont work. And the image that will be draggable is doing weird to.

I called the script jquery and jquery ui in the head.

He is the code i used for my webpage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <style>
    div {
        width:370px;
        height:204px;
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
        border-top-left-radius: 7px;
        border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    }

    #box{
        background:black;
        cursor: move;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }


    #hidden-img{
        display:none;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="box">
        <img src="http://www.hdwallpapersarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/high-resolution-fantasy-woman.jpg" id="hidden-img" />
        <img src="http://www.hdwallpapersarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/high-resolution-fantasy-woman.jpg" id="img" width="371" height="auto" style="top:-0px; left:-0px;" />
    </div>
    <!-- style="top:-262px; left:-425px;" -->
    <div id="zoom"></div> 
    <input type="hidden" id="amount-width" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
    <input type="hidden" id="amount-height" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />

    <div class="text"></div>

    <p>
        Position x:
        <input type="text" id="val-x" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Position y:
        <input type="text" id="val-y" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="file" onchange="readURL(this);" />
    </p>
    <script>
    var previousValue = 0;
    var hiddenImageWidth = $("#hidden-img").width() - 370;

    jQuery("#zoom").slider({
            max: hiddenImageWidth,
            slide: function(event, ui){

            var sliderValue =  jQuery("#zoom").slider("value");
            jQuery("#img").width(370 + sliderValue);

            var pos = $("#img").position(); // returns an object with the attribute top and left
            var top = pos.top;  // top offset position
            var left = pos.left; // left offset position

            $("#val-x").val(left);
            $("#val-y").val(top);

            if (left > 0){
                $("#img").css("left",'0px');
            }

            if (top > 0){
                $("#img").css("top",'0px');
            }

            $("#amount-width").val(jQuery("#img").css("width"));
            $("#amount-height").val(jQuery("#img").css("height"));

            var width = $("#img").width();
            var widthZoom = width + sliderValue;
            var widthVerschil = widthZoom - sliderValue;
            var totalWidth = widthVerschil - '370';

            var height = $("#img").height();
            var totalHeight = height - '207';

            if (sliderValue < previousValue){
              var t, l;
              t = $('#img').position().top;
              l = $('#img').position().left;
              if(t < 0)
                  t = t + (previousValue - sliderValue);
              if(l < 0)
                  l = l + (previousValue - sliderValue);
              $('#img').offset({top: t, left: l});
            }
            previousValue = sliderValue;

            $("#img").draggable({
                containment: [-totalWidth, -totalHeight, 0, 0],
                scroll: false,
                iframeFix: true,
            }); 
            $('.text').html('<br/>The file size = ' + height + ' x ' + widthVerschil);

          }

    });

    var height = $("#img").height();
    var totalHeight = height - '207';

    $("#img").draggable
    ({
        containment: [0, -totalHeight, 0, 0],
        snap: false,
        drag: function(event, ui)
        {
            $("#val-x").val(ui.position.left);
            $("#val-y").val(ui.position.top);

        }   

    });

    $("#img").offset({left: $(this).attr('position')});


    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#img')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)

            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see my script for making al happening is on the end of my body. I tried to put it in my head but that nothing will work, you wont see a slider. ect.

I also tried to place this scripts

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

under my script function. But that wont work either.

I hope somebody see the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your jquery's code inside document ready function:

```
   var previousValue = 0;
 var hiddenImageWidth = $("#hidden-img").width() - 370;


 $(document).ready(function () {
     jQuery("#zoom").slider({
         max: hiddenImageWidth,
         slide: function (event, ui) {

             var sliderValue = jQuery("#zoom").slider("value");
             jQuery("#img").width(370 + sliderValue);

             var pos = $("#img").position(); // returns an object with the attribute top and left
             var top = pos.top; // top offset position
             var left = pos.left; // left offset position

             $("#val-x").val(left);
             $("#val-y").val(top);

             if (left > 0) {
                 $("#img").css("left", '0px');
             }

             if (top > 0) {
                 $("#img").css("top", '0px');
             }

             $("#amount-width").val(jQuery("#img").css("width"));
             $("#amount-height").val(jQuery("#img").css("height"));

             var width = $("#img").width();
             var widthZoom = width + sliderValue;
             var widthVerschil = widthZoom - sliderValue;
             var totalWidth = widthVerschil - '370';

             var height = $("#img").height();
             var totalHeight = height - '207';

             if (sliderValue < previousValue) {
                 var t, l;
                 t = $('#img').position().top;
                 l = $('#img').position().left;
                 if (t < 0) t = t + (previousValue - sliderValue);
                 if (l < 0) l = l + (previousValue - sliderValue);
                 $('#img').offset({
                     top: t,
                     left: l
                 });
             }
             previousValue = sliderValue;

             $("#img").draggable({
                 containment: [-totalWidth, -totalHeight, 0, 0],
                 scroll: false,
                 iframeFix: true,
             });
             $('.text').html('<br/>The file size = ' + height + ' x ' + widthVerschil);

         }

     });

     var height = $("#img").height();
     var totalHeight = height - '207';

     $("#img").draggable({
         containment: [0, -totalHeight, 0, 0],
         snap: false,
         drag: function (event, ui) {
             $("#val-x").val(ui.position.left);
             $("#val-y").val(ui.position.top);

         }

     });

     $("#img").offset({
         left: $(this).attr('position')
     });
 });

 function readURL(input) {
     if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
         var reader = new FileReader();

         reader.onload = function (e) {
             $('#img')
                 .attr('src', e.target.result)

         };
         reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I Tried this but for some reason it still bugging.

Comment: When i look in the console and i try to use the slider he say. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined

Comment: I check your web site code, i don't see your code wrapped in ready function. First try it again. This is a classic problem, only differences between your website code and your jsfiddle is than in jsfiddle, jquery code is wrapped inside onload callback function and jsfiddle use jQuery UI 1.9.2 not jQuery UI 1.10.3 {even this should not affect your code}.

Comment: I have put the code on my website now. Before this i tested in my local browser. The document.ready function is in the code now. And its still not working. I already tried to change it to 1.9.2 but i get the same error.

Comment: For example if I copy the code of http://jqueryui.com/draggable/ Than everything works fine.

Comment: mmh i found something if you look at my code. you see under my document.ready some vars. But he doesnt see the vars at all.